# Use jarsign plugin with assembly plugin in Maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, jar-signing, maven-jarsigner-plugin

I'm using assembly plugin to package a list of applets into zip in one of modules with my maven project. here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<artifactId>applets-deploy</artifactId>
<name>deploy</name>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.activx.lims</groupId>
    <artifactId>applets-common</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.activx.lims</groupId>
    <artifactId>ceplot-applet</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
......  
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/resources.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

what I need is to also sign jars before they are packaged, can I use jarsign plugin here, and how? I can't find where the jar files are temporarily stored during the build process.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pretty normal use of the jarsigner plugin. By default, jars are built by the jar plugin during the package phase and output to the `${project.build.directory}`, which defaults to `target`.

You'd just need to sign the jars some time after they're built during package and before you assemble the zip. You could do that by binding the assembly plugin to a later phase or by adding the jarsigner plugin above the assembly plugin and binding it to the package phase, too.

Comment: but I need to specify "archiveDirectory" in jarsigner plugin, but I don't seem to be able to find the intermediate working directory created with all the jars need to be signed, which later on to be zipped.

Comment: Have you tried the [jarsigner plugin's first usage example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/usage.html)? It shows exactly how to do what you seem to be asking for as far as the jar signing. After that, it's just a matter of making sure the assembly plugin is picking up the signed jars.